# How to map 2 different Lists in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, orm, mapping

I was trying to send a list from a Controller to a View. I thought it would bind, but it's a different type so it won't. *(error: Argument type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' is not assignable to model type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyApp.ViewModels.NewListViewModel>')*. So how am I supposed to map both lists?

Controller

```
 public ActionResult MyData()
    {
        var oldList = db.oldList.Select(x=>x.Name).ToList();
    
// probably here i should add var newList and in some way map with oldList then return to view

        return View(oldList);
    }
```

New list ViewModel

```
 public class NewListViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }
```

My View (MyData)

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.ViewModels.NewListViewModel>
           
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Count)
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Count)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

Comment: You are selecting `Name`, so your `oldList ` is `IEnumerable<string>`, but your view waits for `IEnumerable<NewListViewModel>`

Comment: I know it, but i want to take every Name from oldList and add them to newList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it:

```
    public ActionResult MyData()
        {
            List<NewListViewModel> newList = 
                 db.oldList.Select(x=>new NewListViewModel { Name = x.Name}).ToList();

            return View(newList);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew what i should do, but i wasn't sure how :P

Comment: btw. how can I receive data in controller later? public ActionResult FirstStock(FirstStockViewModel data)
        {} ?

Comment: Declare the model at the top of the razor file (by MVC convention: MyData.cshtml) @model Fully.Qualified.Namespace.NewListViewModel 
and you will be able to access the model's properties in the HTML like so <p>@Model.Name</p>

Answer (score 1):

Just make new `List` of `NewListViewModel` class then fill it with oldList data

```
public ActionResult MyData()
{
    var oldList = db.oldList.Select(x=>x.Name).ToList();
    var newList=new list<NewListViewModel>();
      foreach(var item in oldList)
      {
       newList.Add(new NewListViewModel{Name=item.Name});
      }
    return View(newList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what @arash.zh has suggested. Or you can just use

```
@model dynamic
```

instead of

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.ViewModels.NewListViewModel>
```